# How to verify Windows Defender is running in Sandbox mode?

Tags: security, windows-11, windows-defender, sandbox

I ran this command as admin in Powershell:

```
setx /M MP_FORCE_USE_SANDBOX 1
```

restarted my system, then used process explorer and all I see is this:

[image]

there is no sign of "MsMpEngCP.exe" that this website is talking about:
https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2018/10/26/windows-defender-antivirus-can-now-run-in-a-sandbox/

any idea how to verify if Windows Defender is running in sandboxed mode?

I'm using latest version of Windows 11 insider dev.

Comment: did you run that command inside the sandbox or outside as you are supposed to? Also, its a cmd command

Comment: @LPChip I tried the same command on cmd, restarted, still no sign of sandbox process.

Comment: You will know it works because there will be a process that looks like [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/img_5bd366147e68a.png).  I Suspect this feature might not work on Windows 11. I am finding zero evidence of its support on Windows 11.  Windows Defender has received multiple updates since 2018, any number of those, would invalidated this feature.

Comment: So the updates Windows defender received are an improvement over the sandbox feature and make it even better?

Comment: @lina - 1. You enabled it, and MsMpEng.exe is not running under the content process.  2. The blog is from 201,8 which is 5 years before Windows 11 was released.  3. I have found zero evidence of it existing on Windows 11. 4. Windows Defender has changed significantly in the last 5 years.

Comment: As far as I can see for the newest version of Windows 11 Pro production, Sandbox MODE has been removed and now there is just Sandbox.  I posted such but members wished it deleted and it was. I restored the question to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I am running 64 bit Windows 11 pro 23H2 and it definitely does work.
I see the MsMpEngCP.exe process running as a child of MsMpEng.exe just as it did on Windows 10.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).